# Intelij do not see SciView module for python ploting

Tags: python, matplotlib, intellij-idea, plot

I use Intelij with python [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/631-python) and it's linked to an anaconda environment in order to execute the code. From Settings -> Tools -> Python Scientific -> show plots option is enabled.
When I try to plot something, it throw an error that ends with:

```
    canvas_class = module.FigureCanvas
AttributeError: module 'backend_interagg' has no attribute 'FigureCanvas'
```

From what I read, this happen when plt related methods (e.g `plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))` ) does not a have a canvas space where to plot. Again, I have SciView, but something I think it is not linked correctly.

What can I do? A option would be `matplotlib.use('TkAgg')` but this open a new window for the plot result and it's quite unproperly - it would be much better to plot it directly in SciView

[image]